# AnchorPane homePage = (AnchorPane) loader.load(); not working

Tags: javafx, fxmlloader

Below is the code :

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     System.out.println("Enter start method");
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Bank Account App");
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/Overview.fxml"));
        System.out.println("Location is set");
        AnchorPane homePage = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        OverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(homePage);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Showed successfully");
        this.primaryStage.setWidth(800);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Not Working");;
    }


 }
```

Here is the error message :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409``)
at Question2.Controller.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:40)
```

Why doesnt the line `AnchorPane homePage = (AnchorPane) loader.load();` works?
I am sure that my fxml file has anchor pane as its parent.

Comment: There are [many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+location+not+set) citing this error message. Have you looked at any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Please **add the following opening line** in the highest container in screen's FXML file:

```
fx:controller="com.fxtest.MyController"
```

where *com.fxtest.MyController* is your class containing method a like:

`void buttonOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{`

which is responsible from catching i.e. mouse clicks on buttons...

---

You can also add a controller method in:

SceneBuilder -> Properties (of requested object) -> OnAction

Answer (score -1):

Check what `MainApp.class.getResource("view/Overview.fxml")` actually returns.

Comment: This points the OP in the right direction; it isn't a good answer though since it does not explain the issue, butsimply provides  "debugging advice". Just 2 or 3 more sentences explaining the issue would have made this a OK answer.